# Is there an "Undo" for Quick Edit?

Tags: list, editing-menu, quick-edit

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Is there an "undo" option if a SharePoint user decided they don't want to keep the Quick Edits they made in a List or Document Library?

Thanks

Comment: I think that closing the tab/browser would be enough, yet a ugly way to promote it. Otherwise, if you enter a wrong username/wrong choice value in a field using quick edit and try to save, there will be a dialog mentioning that some columns has errors, and if you would like to go fix them or discard your changes - not saving any change.

Comment: Is this after you click "stop editing"?

Comment: I do not want to click "stop editing." I want to be able to undo the changes made. I asked the SharePoint administrator and he said there is no way to do an undo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [Versioning in SharePoint List](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37).

If versioning will be enable then you can restore old version.